# Will I face any problem if I apply for an India transit or tourist visa in the future if I didn't use the previous one?

Tags: visas, transit

Last year my husband and I applied for an India transit visa to go to Bhutan. I got the visa but my husband didn't, so I could not use my visa that time.

Will there be any problem if I apply for an India transit or tourist visa in the future?

Answer (score 5):

An unused travel visa is probably not a cause for concern. You applied for permission to visit a country (India in your case), that permission was granted, but you simply did not use it. If anybody ever asks about that in the future, you can truthfully say you plans changed and you did not use that visa. This is not an unusual thing.